# How to remove space during button press in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
  processSearch() {
        if ( this.searchHistory.indexOf(this.search) === -1) {
          this.searchHistory.push(this.search);
        }
        this.search = '';
       
      },
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary search-icon" @click="processSearch">
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
```

```js
<input class="form-control bg-light-blue" id="SearchText"  type="text" v-model="search"
        @keydown.enter = 'enter'
        @click="onClick"
        
        @keyup.enter="processSearch"
        @input = 'change'
        @keyup="inputChanged"
        @keydown.down="onArrow"
        @keydown.up="onArrow"
    />
     <ul class="list-group" v-if="showSearchHistory">
            <li class="list-group-item" v-for="(item, index) in searchHistory" :key="index"
              @click="selectPreviousSearch(index)">{{ item }}</li>
          </ul>
```

```html
selectPreviousSearch(index) {
        this.search = this.searchHistory[index];
        this.showSearchHistory = false;
      },
```

I used the above button in search, When I add some content in the search and click on the button, it will show as search history, But the issue is if I directly click on the search button above, some space is reflecting in the search history. So I want to remove the space from the search history if button is clicked directly.

Comment: I think you just need to `trim` the content in the search when the button is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search history should contain the list excluding the empty and white spaces string.
FOr this purpose, you can use `trim`.

```
processSearch() {
        if (  this.searchHistory.indexOf(this.search) === -1 && this.search.trim().length>0) {
          this.searchHistory.push(this.search);
        }
        this.search = '';
       
      },
```

You can add condition : `this.search.trim().length>0`